# Options for showing page borders in "printout" environment?

Tags: pagelayout

I usually work with Printout Screen Environment because I find this convenient when I save files in pdf format.

One of problems with this choice is that I cannot tell where page breaks will occur in the pdf. Although there is an option "Show Page Breaks", I can't seem to get it to show accurate indications for page breaks. I'd like to know where page breaks will occur without continously using PagePreview.

Is it possible to calculate the pages breaks manually and tell the front-end where to draw indicators?  Something like a frame around the page borders, for instance?

Comment: There are some post "Is there a shortcut to select all cells above the current cursor position?" Maybe one could dynamicly calculate their sum of heights in a new window?